# Is it possible to switch keyboard language layout on HTC Wildfire?

Tags: keyboard, languages, htc-wildfire

I am thinking of buying an HTC Wildfire S. Since I will be buying it in Germany, it will have a German keyboard (e.g. Y and Z are interchanged).

**Will there be a way for me to switch the keyboard to English and French and back to German with the click of a button as I do on my Windows PC (ALT-shift)?**

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Gingerbread keyboard should support multiple languages, they can be selected from the `Settings -> Locale and Text -> Gingerbread keyboard -> Input Languages` menu. After this, you'll see the current language on the space bar and can roll through the languages by swiping left or right on the space bar.